# Loop through range of time in half hour increments

Tags: php, loops, time-format

I want to know how to loop a time using 30-minute steps in php. I want the output to be like this:

```
<select style='width:250px;' name='days' onchange='return timeSchedvalue(this.value)'>
  <option value='6:00-6:30 am'>6:00-7:30 am</option>
  <option value='6:30-7:00 am'>6:30-7:00 am</option>
  <option value='7:30-8:00 am'>7:30-8:00 am</option>
  <option value='8:00-8:30 am'>8:00-8:30 am</option>
  <option value='8:30-9:00 am'>8:30-9:00 am</option>
  <option value='9:00-9:30 am'>9:00-9:30 am</option>
  <option value='9:30-10:00 am'>9:30-10:00 am</option>
  <option value='10:00-10:30 am'>10:00-10:30 am</option>
  <option value='10:30-11:00 am'>10:30-11:00 am</option>
  <option value='11:00-11:30 am'>11:00-11:30 am</option>
  <option value='11:30-12:00 am'>11:30-12:00 am</option>
  <option value='12:00-12:30 pm'>12:00-12:30 pm</option>
</select>
```

The loop will starts at 6:00 am - 6:30 am and it will end by 10:00 pm - 10:30 pm.

Answer (score 7):

```
$time = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1);
for ($i = 0; $i < 86400; $i += 1800) {  // 1800 = half hour, 86400 = one day
    printf('<option value="%1$s-%2$s">%1$s-%2$s</option>',
           date('g:i', $time + $i), date('g:i a', $time + $i + 1800));
}
```

Fiddle with the starting time and end condition as required.

Answer (score 3):

Use this if you like.

```
for ($x = 6,$x1 = 1; $x < 22.5; $x+=0.5,$x1++) 
{ 
$gen_date=date('h:i A', mktime(0, 0, 0) + (60 * $x * 60));
$temp=$x+0.5;
$gen_date1=date('h:i A', mktime(0, 0, 0) + (60 * $temp * 60));
echo $x1.'='.$gen_date.'-'.$gen_date1.'<br>';
}
```

Use $x1 as index.
edit as per your need

Answer (score 2):

```
<select style='width:250px;' name='days' onchange='return timeSchedvalue(this.value)'>
<?php
     $time = '6:00'; // start
     for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; $i++)
     {
         $prev = date('g:i a', strtotime($time)); // format the start time
         $next = strtotime('+30mins', strtotime($time)); // add 30 mins
         $time = date('g:i a', $next); // format the next time
         echo "<option value=\"$prev - $time\">$prev - $time</option>";
     }
 ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easiest way is to keep an array of all your intervals and loop through it, perhaps like:

```
array ('06:00', '06:30', '07:00', '07:30'... );
```

Or may be like:

```
array ('06:00 - 06:30', '06:30 - 07:00', '07:00 - 07:30'...);
```

Comment: Why a down vote on my answer? My reputation page says -2 for the down vote? I'll appreciate if the voter may please explain his/her thought

Comment: I did not down vote but I believe it was because you hard coded the values.

Comment: Yeah, may be! I only wanted to give an idea to the solution ;-). Anyways, it doesn't make sense to make it dynamic unless the intervals might change.

Comment: the purpose of dynamic coding is to write more scalable, simplified code which in turn becomes even more elegant. what you wrote was technically feasible but not the best answer, perhaps. i would use it, though, in cases of extremely close deadlines, lol

Answer (score 1):

You can create time with [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) and format it with [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

In your case you need to create a start time 6:00 am -> mktime(6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

then you need to add 30 min for each next time...

This can be easily done in a for loop:

```
<select style='width:250px;' name='days' onchange='return timeSchedvalue(this.value)'>
<?php
 for ($i = 0; $i <= 960; $i+=30) {
    $time1 = date('h:i a', mktime(6, $i, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    $time2 = date('h:i a', mktime(6, $i+30, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    echo "<option value='" . $time1 . " - " . $time2 . "'>" .$time1 . " - " . $time2 . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through a DateTime period after establishing the first start and last start time (the end time is "inclusive" thanks to the fourth parameter of the dateperiod declaration).  Set the interval for 30 minutes, then loop.  As you iterate, `modify()` the current datetime object by an additional 30 minutes to create the end time for each range.

Notice that I separated the `a` (am/pm) expression -- this is because you wish for `11:30 - 12:00` to say `am`.  If `modify()` was called first, then `a` would be `pm`.  Consequently, I've changed the order of the placeholders in the  first parameter of `printf()` -- `%3$s` is written before `%2$s`.

This is also a perfect time to inform you that there is no benefit in bloating your html markup with `value` attribute values that are identical to your option text.  Form submissions and javascript operations will still work exactly the same without error.  When they are the same, do not repeat the option text as the option `value`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/oghUp))

```
$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('today 06:00:00'),
    new DateInterval('PT30M'),
    new DateTime('today 22:00:00'),
    DatePeriod::INCLUDE_END_DATE
);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    printf(
        '<option>%1$s - %3$s %2$s</option>' . "\n",
        $dt->format('h:i'),
        $dt->format('a'),
        $dt->modify('+30 minutes')->format('h:i')
    );
}
```

Output:

```
<option>06:00 - 06:30 am</option>
<option>06:30 - 07:00 am</option>
<option>07:00 - 07:30 am</option>
<option>07:30 - 08:00 am</option>
<option>08:00 - 08:30 am</option>
<option>08:30 - 09:00 am</option>
<option>09:00 - 09:30 am</option>
<option>09:30 - 10:00 am</option>
<option>10:00 - 10:30 am</option>
<option>10:30 - 11:00 am</option>
<option>11:00 - 11:30 am</option>
<option>11:30 - 12:00 am</option>
<option>12:00 - 12:30 pm</option>
<option>12:30 - 01:00 pm</option>
<option>01:00 - 01:30 pm</option>
<option>01:30 - 02:00 pm</option>
<option>02:00 - 02:30 pm</option>
<option>02:30 - 03:00 pm</option>
<option>03:00 - 03:30 pm</option>
<option>03:30 - 04:00 pm</option>
<option>04:00 - 04:30 pm</option>
<option>04:30 - 05:00 pm</option>
<option>05:00 - 05:30 pm</option>
<option>05:30 - 06:00 pm</option>
<option>06:00 - 06:30 pm</option>
<option>06:30 - 07:00 pm</option>
<option>07:00 - 07:30 pm</option>
<option>07:30 - 08:00 pm</option>
<option>08:00 - 08:30 pm</option>
<option>08:30 - 09:00 pm</option>
<option>09:00 - 09:30 pm</option>
<option>09:30 - 10:00 pm</option>
<option>10:00 - 10:30 pm</option>
```

Comment: I modified to have only first times in EU format.
`$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('today 10:00:00'),
    new DateInterval('PT30M'),
    new DateTime('tomorrow 02:00:00')
);
        
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    printf(
        '<option value="%1$s">%1$s</option>' . "\n",
        $dt->format('H:i')
    );
    $dt->modify('+30 minutes')->format('H:i');
}`

Comment: @Sis As already mentioned in my answer, do not duplicate the option's text as the option's value attribute -- there is no benefit at all. You don't need to reuse or reorder the placeholders, so you can just use `"<option>%s</option>\n"`.  Since you are not creating time ranges, you will not need to call `modify()` inside of the loop -- the loop will increment the times.  https://3v4l.org/qqPln

Comment: Output for 8.1.0 - 8.1.27 throws errors on that site

Comment: @Sis, this will work all the way down to PHP5.5 https://3v4l.org/hmeGP

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it. You're basically adding blocks of 30 mins to a time and looping till you get the correct number of options.

```
//get the timestamp for 6.30 am
$time   = strtotime('6.30 am'); //not important what the date is.

//start adding 30mins
$times      = array();
$halfHour   = 60 * 30;
$blocks     = 12; //adjust this to get the number of options
while ($blocks) {
    $times[]  = date('h:i', $time) . ' - ' . date('h:i a', ($time += $halfHour)); //I keep incrementing the time by half an hour
    $blocks--;
}
var_dump($times);
```

Answer (score 0):

This simply loops through every half our and then calls date on each.

```
$inc   = 30 * 60;
$start = (strtotime('6AM')); // 6  AM
$end   = (strtotime('10PM')); // 10 PM

echo "<select>";
for( $i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += $inc )
{
    // to the standart format
    $range = date( 'g:i', $i ) . ' - ' . 
             // $inc = 30 minutes so this will be .5 hr later
             date( 'g:i A', $i + $inc );
    echo "<option value=\"$range\">$range</option>" . PHP_EOL;
}
echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $timeFormat = "%02d:%02d";
    $startHour = 6;
    $endHour = 12;
    $timeInterval = 30; // in minutes

    $currentHour = $startHour;
    $currentMinute = 0;
    while ($currentHour <= $endHour) {
        $timeRange = sprintf($timeFormat, $currentHour, $currentMinute) . ($currentHour < 12 ? " am" : " pm");

        $currentMinute = $currentMinute + $timeInterval;
        if ($currentMinute > 59) {
            $currentHour++;
            $currentMinute = $currentMinute - 60;
        }

        $timeRange .= " - " . sprintf($timeFormat, $currentHour, $currentMinute) . ($currentHour < 12 ? " am" : " pm");

        if ($currentHour <= $endHour) {
            echo "## " . $timeRange . "\n";         
        }       
    }

?>
```